# AWS Amplify with React Native: Credentials should be scoped to a valid region, not us-east-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I am trying to make a simple get request using the AWS Amplify SDK for React Native and an IAM Authorizer in API Gateway. I always get the following error message:

> Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-east-1'.

What am I doing wrong? Heres my code (does not do anything yet):

```
function getImageIdForUpload() {
    let apiName = 'MyAPIGatewayAPI';
    let path = '/upload-image/get-new-id';
    let myInit = {
        // replace this with attributes you need
    };

    API.get(apiName, path, myInit).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error.response)
    });
}
```

My config:

```
Auth: {
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'eu-central-1:xxxx',
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'eu-central-1',
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'eu-central-1_xxxx',
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxx',
    },
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution myself: You have to set the region in your API config.

Example:

```
API: {
        endpoints: [
            {
                name: "MyAPIGatewayAPI",
                endpoint: "https://xxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev",
                region: "eu-central-1"
            }
        ]
    },
```

It might not be an issue if the API is set to "Edge optimized".